# Where can I play against specific openings?

Tags: opening, training, websites

Is there a website where you can play against real people with an opening already installed by default? For example, I want to play against the English opening, but my opponents rarely play it, so I want to practice somewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want, Chess.com allows you to play from a custom opening position against a computer, which you can choose your level. If you need help with it, go here. You can also send a game to a friend.

https://support.chess.com/article/684-how-can-i-play-the-computer-from-a-custom-position

Lichess does a similar thing. Create your personal board, and press continue from here to play with a computer or a friend.

Comment: Additionally, chess.com tournaments allow you to setup a specific position, and play with others as a whole. example: https://www.chess.com/tournament/ruy-lopez-open-50 (ruy lopez tourney)

Answer (score 11):

Lichess also has several thematic tournaments throughout the week.
As an example take a look at this thematic Italian game arena tournament:

[image]

When you open the tournament, the opening is mentioned in the upper left corner if there is one:

[image]

It is a link so you can click it to see the mentioned opening.

Alternatively you can create your own tournament with a opening of your choice. For that just go to the create tournament area and set the starting position:

[image]

In that box you have to place a FEN string. For the English opening considering only `1 C4`, you can use the following fen:

`rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/2P5/8/PP1PPPPP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq - 0 1`

Regardless you can create any fen of your choice with the lichess [analysis board tool](https://lichess.org/analysis) or the [opening explorer](https://lichess.org/analysis#explorer)

Answer (score 1):

There are theme tournaments on ICCF. [Example](https://www.iccf.com/EventAnnouncement.aspx?id=87920) for the Alapin variation of the Sicilian. However, it is correspondence chess, which might not be your cup of tea.

Answer (score 0):

[echecsemail.com](https://echecsemail.com) allows you to create games and tournaments dedicated to specific openings.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Maia chess bots on Lichess, e.g. `maia1` and `maia5` (there are multiple bots with different elo ratings). They're designed to play like humans. You can challenge them to a game from any position using From Position.

Answer (score 0):

i could swear there's a feature in chessdotcom that allows you to play correspondence chess from a certain opening...wait yeah see here:

> [image]

you can even see what you're getting into:

> [image]

idk what sites have live versions these. but man before i quit chess for 9LX i sure wished there were live versions of these.

so far the answers talk of tournaments or bots. the bot option sounds lame, but idk if it works for you then go ahead. the tournament thing seems like the closest we're gonna get for now. but i think it's a pretty good option. i mean, not sure what a queue for specific openings would look like.